# Unity3d Calculate remaing time for a decreasing value

Tags: unity-game-engine, time

Hello Stack overflow community, im actually a beginner in scripting and try to explain my problem as good as possible.
please be patient with my try of explanation :)

the situation is the following...

i have a float var "energy" for example and on every fixed update it loose some of the energy over time "energy drain" using time.deltatime

my goal is to calculate how many seconds left before the value "energy" hits 0.0f

it would be nice if someone can answer me with a link to an example or write down some pseudocode.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I assume you are doing something like
>
> ```
> energy -= energyDecreasePerSecond * Time.deltaTime;
> ```
>
> so you mean something like
>
> ```
> var secondToGo = energy * energyDecreasePerSecond;
> ```

-derHugo

You want to divide by `energyDecreasePerSecond` instead.

Example:

```
var secondToGo = energy / energyDecreasePerSecond;
```

Comment: Thank you. it worked perfectly. and afterwards, like always XD, i cant understand why i wasnt able to solve this by myself.
now i try to format the outcoming secondToGo as a time, but this issue i try to solve by myself. 

thanks for the great and fast reaction!!!

Comment: Often It helps if I write things out algebraically then I can rearrange my formulas any way I like

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are doing something like

```
energy -= energyDecreasePerSecond * Time.deltaTime;
```

so you mean something like

```
var secondsToGo = energy / energyDecreasePerSecond;
```